# Android Style Split does not work, explanation needed

Tags: android, styles

i am trying to change the style of the action bar in android.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<style name="GoetheTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/GoetheActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="GoetheActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/base_color_dark</item>
</style>
```

So yeah, thats what I got. Now I have put the application theme in the android manifest to the created one (GoetheTheme). But the ActionBar does not change. If I set it to @GoetheActionBar, it does. Why does GoetheTheme style don't take the GoetheActionBar style?

Can please someone explain me the style system? I really dont get it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, my very bad. I found out, I have to use a different parameter as parent ^^

I took a Light theme based one not android specific.

Correct:

```
<style name="GoetheActionBar"parent="@android:style/Theme.WithActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/base_color_dark</item>
</style>

<style name="GoetheTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/GoetheActionBar</item>
</style>
```